# WebClient on Store Universal Apps

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, browser, httpclient

I'm using this code on Windows Desktop App to get the values of a combobox that I after need to select which is going to update the page with new information using JavaScript

```
private WebBrowser withEventsField_wb;
WebBrowser wb {
    get { return withEventsField_wb; }
    set {
        if (withEventsField_wb != null) {
            withEventsField_wb.Navigated -= navigated;
        }
        withEventsField_wb = value;
        if (withEventsField_wb != null) {
            withEventsField_wb.Navigated += navigated;
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.Navigate("https://academicos.ubi.pt/online/horarios.aspx?p=a");
}

private void navigated()
{
    HtmlElementCollection allelements = wb.Document.All;
    HtmlElement year = default(HtmlElement);

    foreach (HtmlElement webpageelement in allelements) {
        if (webpageelement.GetAttribute("id").Contains("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAnoLect") == true) {
            year = webpageelement;
            HtmlElementCollection yoptions = year.Children;

            foreach (HtmlElement yopt in yoptions) {
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(yopt.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I'm trying to do the same on Universal App (Windows Phone/Windows) but I'm being unable to do the same. I know that I have to use HttpClient but it does not work like a WebBrowser, this web browser is only created by code to get all the data needed and as for each step of data that I need to retrieve the website does not refresh normally but uses jQuery to load the new information.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a lot of searching I got something that helps and even gave me other idea
http://blog.gauravchouhan.com/tag/advance-web-scraping-using-c/